# how to use nested row span using angularJS?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using nested array in angularjs and bootstrap and that is dynamically coming from server side code.In that displaying table format using rowspan but it is working two level nested array only need to have more level.I tried plunker code.In this example using sample only but I need more levels

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>check</td>
                    <th>Member</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Branch</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody ng-repeat="group in groups">
                <tr ng-repeat="member in group.members">
                    <td rowspan="{{group.members.length}}" ng-hide="$index>0">
                       {{group.id}}
                    </td>
                    <td  >
                    {{member.name}}

                    </td>
                   <td >
                    {{member.age}}

                    </td>


                    <td > 
                   <table >
                         <tbody>
                       <tr  ng-repeat="stu in member.student" >
                       <td >{{stu.Branch}}</td>
                       </tr>

                       </tbody>
                       </table>
                   </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/95xk4wvg/1/)

Comment: What do you want to achieve? everything is printing fine

Comment: I need border in every column like last column there is no borders

Answer (score 0):

You did not add class="table" for inner table.
Also give `padding:0px` to `td`
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sanketdhoble/95xk4wvg/31/)

```
<td style="padding:0px">
  <table class="table">
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="stu in member.student" >
       <td>{{stu.Branch}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</td>
```

Comment: it showing borders but the process is not working good in my app.because it showing like textfield borders.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sanketdhoble/95xk4wvg/31/   This fiddle looks good. What fo you mean by text-field borders?